# Python: avoiding nested for-loop NLP edition; any lib-support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to make a user-query based autosuggest. I have a bunch of aggregated queries like:

```
QUERY          COUNT
"harry potter" 100
"iron man"     93
"harry pott"   32
"harr pott"    5
```

with around 200.000 rows. As you can see some users are extensively using the prefixed search typing in only the first letters of a word. Those queries in the example should be aggregated with a full "harry potter" row.

Now assuming that the majority of users searches with full words, I think I can do that aggregation effectively (avoiding a nested for-loop over the whole index) in the following way:

I sort the tokens in the query alphabetically and generate a map "first_token" like:

```
"h"         "harry potter"
"ha"        "harry potter"
"har"       "harry potter"
"harr"      "harry potter"
"harry"     "harry potter"
```

and respectively "second_token" and so forth...

```
"p"         "harry potter"
"po"        "harry potter"
"pot"       "harry potter"
"pott"      "harry potter"
"potte"     "harry potter"
"potter"    "harry potter"
```

and then I iterate from top to bottom and for each element like "harr pott" I check if there is an element in both "first_token" and "second_token" whose value is the same document, eg "harry potter" and that document is not identical to the original ("harr pott") and has a higher score, in which case I aggregate it. The runtime of this should be O(index_size * max_number_of_tokens).

Now I was wondering if there is any lib for Python that can make it easier for me implementing all of this. Coming from Java/JS I am not so familiar with Python yet, I just know it has lots of tools for NLP.

Can anything in NLTK or so help me? I think there should be at least a tool for vectorizing strings. Perhaps using that you can do the "starts-with" operation as a simple lookup without generating tries-maps manually?

Comment: Try `trie` structures =)

Comment: @alvas yup that's what I was describing. In fact I don't even need full tries, they can start with the smallest tokens I have (around 3 characters) instead of single letters. My question is if there is a module for doing just that

Comment: Maybe https://pypi.org/project/datrie/ ?

Comment: @alvas ah yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Autosuggest and many other features specific to **search** are handled well in `Lucene`. You can try Python implementation of it [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/)

Alternatively, if you want answer limited to the specifics of the question you have asked, try out `ngram` module of Python. Details [here](https://pythonhosted.org/ngram/ngram.html)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I am using ElasticSearch which is built on top of Lucene. Lucene is doing a great job of providing a quick suggest function, which in the newer versions is built with tries, as far as I know. The problem is to create suggest data in the first place; that's what I try to do right now. But I will check out the ngram module; it might indeed be just what I am looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are already using ElasticSearch and your issue is around creating database for suggestions, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882927/how-to-insert-data-into-elasticsearch

Comment: No, I can work with ElasticSearch just fine, my issue is data-cleaning